# Issue with string length 76

Tags: c, strlen, strncpy

I am at a loss here.
Will post my code in a short while...just that its too long to extract portions of the "troubling" giving code. Will expalin my issue here: I store a string(path to a file or directory) in an array of structure `{ char *path; size_t path_len}` where `path` is the string and `path_en` its length. On inserting the `path_len` is 76. On extracting from the array with `strncpy` the string length becomes 78 or even a simple `strlen` of the string within the array says 77.

All other cases with original string length lesser then 77 works just fine.

I am baffled.

Comment: you sure you're not counting an extra \n or \r character?

Comment: I guess it's something about allocating memory for that string. Please don't forget the code that allocates memory for the string.

Comment: Like I said it works perfectly with all other string length accept 76...Is this somehing to do with the base64 thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With strncpy -- do you remember to null terminate the resulting copied string?

Strncpy does not null terminate strings if they are longer than N (N being the 3rd argument you pass to strncpy)